# swapping between two versions of NetBeans plugins

Tags: netbeans

I'm working with a team on a NetBeans plugin and trying to compare the behavior between an earlier version and a later version... is there any easy way to do this? Looks like I have to uninstall version A, restart, install version B, restart, then to switch back I have to uninstall version B, restart, install version A, restart.

Comment: Does your plugin install itself in the userdir or globally? If your plugin installs itself in the userdir, you can just start NetBeans with different userdirs (`--userdir ...`)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name could you expand upon this as an answer and clarify what this means? It may work for me, in which case I will award you the bounty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will likely want to run two instances of the same NetBeans version if using Windows.  There seems to be an easy way to do set this up based on copying the NetBeans application directory:

http://netbeans.tusharjoshi.com/2008/12/opening-multiple-netbeans-ide-instances.html

Given you likely have version A of the plugin installed, it will likely be copied to both folders with the existing plugins.  You will have to uninstall A from the second NetBeans application directory, restart, install B, restart, and run the side-by-side comparison.

I am not sure about OSX or Linux since the NetBeans module directory is outside the hierarchy of the application folder.  If I recall correctly, the application reads the plugin information from a module.xml file during startup.  Re-configuring that file is going to be technically harder that the following option.

There may be other options that play off this same idea (e.g. run as another user, install slightly different version).  You may simply want to  install a slightly higher/lower NetBeans version alongside your current version.  Since the plugin directories are typically in child directories relative to the major and minor version numbers, the module and plugin paths are going to be different.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried doing something like this?:

```
#if VERSION_A
    //Do things for Version A
#elif VERSION_B
    //Do things for Version B
#endif
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with the C programming language.

Comment: You're using C specifically;  or C#/C++??

Comment: Netbeans plugins are Java-based.

Comment: Didn't know you couldn't do that in Java.  Now I do.  See - learn something every day